# Css positioning columns

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to make a simple css framework which allows me to switch from layouts like sidebar-content, sidebar-sidebar-content etc.. the problem i'm facing is with the sidebar-content-sidebar layout.
The html code looks like

```
<div class="content">
<h2>Content</h2>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-alt">
<h2>sidebar-alt</h2>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
<h2>sidebar</h2>
</div>
```

I've tried using floats but can't seem to get the content div to be in the centre of the two sidebars.

Using a bit of css like so is was able to achieve it

```
body.sidebar-content-sidebar #container.width-960 .content {
    width: 460px;
    position: relative; 
    left: 160px;
    top: 55px;
}
body.sidebar-content-sidebar #container.width-960 .sidebar {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 55px;
    left: 639px;

}
body.sidebar-content-sidebar #container.width-960 .sidebar-alt {
    width: 140px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 55px;
}
```

However the navigation which is superfish now doesn't work. Is there anyway of positioning the columns using simple floats? Or what is the solution?

Comment: You might want to consider using margin:auto and not setting a width on the center part and

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AygDy/ works for me...content is in the middle of the sidebars

Comment: Do you have a test page, or could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) / [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) example?

Comment: You're question on using floats is very apt and the code posted above is inappropriate use of absolute positioning.  Consider this link: http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/ No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put content in the "center" in the html and then just float them all left. Don't Worry about setting top and left.

```
<div class="sidebar-alt">
<h2>sidebar-alt</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
<h2>Content</h2>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
<h2>sidebar</h2>
</div>
```

Another way is

```
<div class="left" style="float:left;">
 <div class="sidebar-alt"  style="float:left;">
 <h2>sidebar-alt</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="content"  style="float:right;">
 <h2>Content</h2>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar" style="float:right;">
<h2>sidebar</h2>
</div>
```

Make sure to set the width.
Here is an example http://ewsbuild.com/~johnsplu/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good start to what you are trying to do:

```
div.content {
    width: 460px;
    position: relative; 
    left: 160px;
    top: 55px;
    background-color: red;
}
div.sidebar {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 55px;
    left: 639px;
    background-color: green;
}
div.sidebar-alt {
    width: 140px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 55px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The 'background-color's are only there to visualize the divs. (may also help you with the margins)